# Как так сверстать?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть такой макет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом макете видим, что есть блок с новостями, и в этом блоке - карточки новостей. Но, если пригледеться, видно, что расположение этих карточек нарушает строки и карточка второй строки "заплывает" в первую строку
(карточка третьей строки заплывает на вторую строку и т.д.).
Пока получилось сделать только так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.newsfeed-news-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 8em;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.news-card__title.index-swiper-slide-info__title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.news-card__tag.index-swiper-slide-info__tag {
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  /* line-height: 1.5em; */
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.news-card-footer {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.news-card-footer-views {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img.news-card-footer-views__icon {
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.news-card {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.news-card__image {
  width: 100%;
}

.news-card-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
}

.news-card-footer-views {
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.news-card-footer-views__icon {
  width: 16px;
}

.newsfeed-news__title {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.newsfeed-more-load {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 3em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #CB9374;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn:hover path,
.newsfeed-more-load__btn:hover {
  background-color: #CB9374;
  color: #fff;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__arrow {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.index-swiper-slide-info__tag {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #CB9374;
}

.index-swiper-slide-info__title {
  font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:wght@400;500&family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600&family=Raleway:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>so</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="newsfeed-news">
    <div class="newsfeed-news-cards">
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6X228Zj/news-image.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hfHNNmF/news-image3.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HPgrBG7/news-image4.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
        <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
        <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer">
          <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
          <div class="news-card-footer-views">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
            <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Как так сверстать? Или как сделать, чтобы блок на второй строке заплыл на первую строку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант с использованием системы компоновки элементов CSS Flexbox.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.newsfeed-news-cards {
  /*display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 8em;
  align-items: baseline;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.news-card__title.index-swiper-slide-info__title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.news-card__tag.index-swiper-slide-info__tag {
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  /* line-height: 1.5em; */
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.news-card-footer {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.news-card-footer-views {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img.news-card-footer-views__icon {
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.news-card {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.news-card__image {
  width: 100%;
}

.news-card-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
}

.news-card-footer-views {
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.news-card-footer-views__icon {
  width: 16px;
}

.newsfeed-news__title {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.newsfeed-more-load {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 3em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #CB9374;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn:hover path,
.newsfeed-more-load__btn:hover {
  background-color: #CB9374;
  color: #fff;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__arrow {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.index-swiper-slide-info__tag {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #CB9374;
}

.index-swiper-slide-info__title {
  font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsfeed-news">
  <div class="newsfeed-news-cards">

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6X228Zj/news-image.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hfHNNmF/news-image3.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HPgrBG7/news-image4.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Самый простой вариант с использованием свойства `column-count:`, которое определяет количество колонок. На примере ниже выстраиваем картинки в три колонки `column-count: 3;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.newsfeed-news-cards {
  /*display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 8em;
  align-items: baseline;*/
  column-count: 3;
  padding: 5px;
}

.news-card__title.index-swiper-slide-info__title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.news-card__tag.index-swiper-slide-info__tag {
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  /* line-height: 1.5em; */
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.news-card-footer {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #BDBDBD;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.news-card-footer-views {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img.news-card-footer-views__icon {
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.news-card {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.news-card__image {
  width: 100%;
}

.news-card-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
}

.news-card-footer-views {
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.news-card-footer-views__icon {
  width: 16px;
}

.newsfeed-news__title {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.newsfeed-more-load {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 3em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #CB9374;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__btn:hover path,
.newsfeed-more-load__btn:hover {
  background-color: #CB9374;
  color: #fff;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.newsfeed-more-load__arrow {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.index-swiper-slide-info__tag {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #CB9374;
}

.index-swiper-slide-info__title {
  font-family: 'Lora', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsfeed-news">
  <div class="newsfeed-news-cards">

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6X228Zj/news-image.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hfHNNmF/news-image3.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/HPgrBG7/news-image4.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/RPp1jVG/news-image1.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-card">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/ssMP4zb/news-image2.png" alt="" class="news-card__image" />
      <div class="news-card__tag index-swiper-slide-info__tag">коронавирус</div>
      <div class="news-card__title index-swiper-slide-info__title">Эксперт назвал отличия между первой и второй волнами COVID-19</div>
      <div class="news-card-footer">
        <div class="news-card-footer__post-date">2 часа назад</div>
        <div class="news-card-footer-views">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yYj3Z4j/eye.png" alt="" class="news-card-footer-views__icon">
          <span class="news-card-footer-views__count">178</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Такую же сетку можно выстраивать и с помощью CSS Grid. Однако, на мой взгляд, эффективнее всего для этих целей использовать библиотеку [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Данная "технология" называется - masonry (что-то типо кладки).
Можно воспользоваться JS библиотекой:
https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: К сожалению я не могу дать больше информации с телефона, но помочь человеку хочется. Но я добавил, как называется "технология", по ней можно с легкостью найти больше информации, примеров и различных библиотек для реализации.